# c++ different error depends on whether or not I'm printing a variable

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault

**Preface**
This is probably a bad question but I'm truly hopeless here. I know that I my question is a bad one since it is highly specific to my problem but I'll try to describe the problem the best and most general way I can...

**Some background**
In my code, I have a data structure named `bead` which holds, among other an integer variable named `LID`. I also have a data structure named `lipid` which holds, among others, three pointers to (three different) `bead`s. The `lipid`s are held in a `vector<lipid*>` variable named `lipids` and `bead`'s `LID` variable is equal to the position of the appropriate `lipid` in `lipids` +1.

During my (Monte Carlo - MC) simulation, I choose a random number between 0 and 999 and change appropriate `lipid`. I then test the change using a function named `calcEnergy` which accept the `lipid`'s `bead` pointers one at a time as it's input (named `mb`).

**The problem**
I got a bad allocation error after I have picked `lipids` position number 261. I have tried to find why does that happen so I have typed:

```
if(mb->LID ==261){
  printf("something");
}
```

when I tried this, The simulation stopped (segmentation fault) when the program have picked `lipids` position number 132. So, I tried to see why is that and printed to the screen the `LID` of each `bead` I have sent using `printf()`. Now the program survive the 132 `lipid` and crushes on the next `lipid`.

I am absolutely clueless about the cause of why does the program crashes when I try to read a variable which I know it's valid.

Once again, I know this is a long shot but I have now other idea...

Thanks.

Comment: Run it under valgrind - that will help to nail the problem which is probably somewhere prior to the symptoms you are witnessing. Also you say this is C++ but you are using C functions such as printf - are you writing in C or C++ ?

Comment: I'm using c++. mainly for the use of containers and objects.

Comment: Any luck with valgrind ?

Comment: I can't tell yet, it's running. Thanks...

Comment: Without seeing the actual code, I don't think your question can be answered.

Comment: OK - it will probably run somewhat slower under valgrind but hopefully it should take you straight to the error. A bit late to mention this but ideally you should have compiled with debug symbols on (e.g. `gcc -g`).

Comment: Thanks to this: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html#quick-start.prepare I have found out.

Comment: @Paul R: Tons and tons of C++ programmers are using C I/O because C++ iostreams suck badly.

Comment: @Vlad: I have some sympathy with that. The reason I asked is that a lot of beginner-level questions on SO get tagged as C++ because the poster is using e.g. MSVC++, but it turns out that the actual code is more C than C++.

Comment: Do you have a good reason to use `vector<lipid*>` instead of `vector<lipid>`? Does `calcEnergy` use `LID` at all? Are you sure that the bead's `LID` is really equal to the position (+1) of the the lipid that points to that bead? Does the code always crash on the first of the three beads?

Comment: @Beta I use the pointer because of the structure of the code, I keep multiple vectors of ``lipid``s and ``bead``of different types. I use the ``LID`` parameter to make sure that no two ``bead``s of the same ``lipid`` are interacting. I'm not absolutely sure, but I don't count on this...

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that a function is taking in a lipid * and overwriting one of its bead pointers, so that later, it reads an invalid pointer which contains invalid bead data.

Try editing your "calc energy" function to not do anything, just take in the pointer and return. See if that stops the bug. If it does, add one line of code at a time until you find the line that causes the error.

Comment: This is my favorite for of debugging, the problem with it is that I can't tell if this line cause the bug or only throw the exception. Anyhow, I have used Paul R tip and I have found that I don't free a pointer, now I need to find out which pointer...